# how to handle json response and display the values in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using `openweather` api to get weather data.when i enter the city name  the server returns a json data I need to know how to handle the data and i need to display the data inside a div

```js
function loadweather() {
  var q = document.getElementById("in").value;
  var appid = document.getElementById("appid").value;
  var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + q + '&appid=' + appid;
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="in" value="New Delhi"/>
<input type="hidden" id="appid" value="086a3e2bd775aac95a9b096b5233f049">
<button id="go" onclick="loadweather()">Search</button>
<div id="disp"></div>
```

Comment: What data you need to display? i.e. `data.weather.main` will fetch you `Haze`

Comment: does `console.log(data)` print what you want to?

Comment: you can use JSON.parse(data) method to access the json value. By the way what data you need to display from the json data?

Comment: i need to display temperature @satpal

Comment: one small request can you run this code bcoz i am getting error          **jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4 GET http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=%27%20+%20q%20+%20%27&appid=%27%20+%20appid 401 (Unauthorized)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the data You got as an object. In your case the object will be as shown below.

```
public class RootObject
{
public Coord coord { get; set; }
public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
public string @base { get; set; }
public Main main { get; set; }
public int visibility { get; set; }
public Wind wind { get; set; }
public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
public int dt { get; set; }
public Sys sys { get; set; }
public int id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public int cod { get; set; }
```

}

You can access it script itself as shown below.

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            $('#disp').html('Temperature:' + data.main.temp + 'deg Fahrenheit' + 'Pressure:'+ data.main.pressure)
        });